# Can't get .selected class to change on nav item click

Tags: jquery, selecteditem, jquery-isotope

Despite almost completely copying this filtering [demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html), I still can't get the the plugin to remove the `.selected` class from the current element and add it to the one being clicked.

The current result is that the items do filter, but the `.selected` class remains assigned to `<li><a href="#videos" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>`.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="category_navigation option-set" data-option-key="filter"> 
    <li><a href="#videos" data-filter="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos" data-filter=".feature">Feature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos" data-filter=".commercial">Commercial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos" data-filter=".music_video">Music Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos" data-filter=".trailer-promo">Trailer/Promo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos" data-filter=".digital">Digital</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
// cache container
var $container = $('.videos');
// initialize isotope
$container.isotope({
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('[href="#videos"]').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
```

**Item HTML sample**

```
<li class="trailer-promo">
    <a href='http://player.vimeo.com/video/55078437?autoplay=1' 
        class='lightview' 
        data-lightview-group='trailer/promo'
        data-lightview-type='iframe' 
        data-lightview-title="KUNG FU PANDA 2"
        data-lightview-caption="20 Intl.<br>Dir: Dreamworks/Aspect Ratio"
        data-lightview-options="width: 796, height: 447, viewport: 'scale'">
        <img src="img/video_thumbs/TRAILER_KUNG-FU-PANDA_2.jpg" alt="">
        <p>KUNG FU PANDA 2</p>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="feature">
    <a href='http://player.vimeo.com/video/16129275?autoplay=1' 
        class='lightview' 
        data-lightview-group='feature'
        data-lightview-type='iframe' 
        data-lightview-title="RAY CHARLES AMERICA"
        data-lightview-caption="Client: Tremolo Productions<br>Dir: Alexis Spraic"
        data-lightview-options="width: 796, height: 447, viewport: 'scale'">
        <img src="img/video_thumbs/FEATURE_RAY-CHARLES-AMERICA.jpg" alt="">
        <p>RAY CHARLES AMERICA</p>
    </a>
</li>

<li class="commercial">
    <a href='http://player.vimeo.com/video/28387434?autoplay=1' 
        class='lightview' 
        data-lightview-group='commercial'
        data-lightview-type='iframe' 
        data-lightview-title="VIEWDLE"
        data-lightview-caption="Third Eye<br>Dir: Blake & Nic"
        data-lightview-options="width: 796, height: 447, viewport: 'scale'">
        <img src="img/video_thumbs/COMMERCIAL_THIRD-EYE.jpg" alt="">
        <p>VIEWDLE</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any code in there to actually remove the class.  I don't know anything about that plugin, but you could just do something like this:

```
$(".selected").removeClass("selected");
```

and add the class back to whatever element you need/want it attached to.

Comment: For those interested, code I put into production was:
 $('.category_navigation li a').click(function(){
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass('selected')
 });